# Json modelling issue

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I'm currently working with the following json structure and I'm not sure how to model it on my classes, since I've never run into this kind of structure before. Would appreciate any leads or help:

```
{ "messages": { "1": { "tid": "309", "status": "0", "timestamp": "1379795079", "uid": "1111111111", "txt": "sometext" }, "2": { "tid": "310", "status": "0", "timestamp": "1379795523", "uid": "2222222222", "txt": "sometext2" } }, "status": 1 }
```

The messages value objects are not a common json structure that i know of, I understand that these are objects, but I don't know how to map them with my classes.

Answer (score 0):

I Use **[json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)**, to model my objects for me. Consider the following json object:

```
{
    "employees": [
    { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
    { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
    { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }]
}
```

I get these objects from the tool:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Employee> employees { get; set; }
}
```

Source: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me static structures with no arrays or any other kind of dynamic structure. Thanks anyway

Comment: @mtopp maybe you should post your real json.

Comment: Posted in main question

Answer (score 0):

Technically, your json object is a *dictionary*, *associative array* or even *hash-table* (select appropriate for your target language). Such a data structure is a perfectly reasonable thing to serialize.

However, that particular object would probably have been better serialized as something like:

```
{ "messages":
  [
    { "tid": "309"
    , "status": "0"
    , "timestamp": "1379795079"
    , "uid": "1111111111"
    , "txt": "sometext"
    }
  ,
    { "tid": "310"
    , "status": "0"
    , "timestamp": "1379795523"
    , "uid": "2222222222"
    , "txt": "sometext2" }
    }
  ]
, "status": 1
}
```

(unless the sender wanted the option of sending the individual messages items out of order). That's certainly how I would represent it.

Comment: I'll be marking this as valid, since i had the same suspiciuos about it ;). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've solved it:

public class MessagesResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("messages")]
        public Dictionary Messages { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }

THanks to @rici, I've realized that the use of a dictionary would solve the problem